# java URLConnection to http URL and extracting XML response

Tags: java, xml, rest

I have a rest http URL from which I have to extract the XML response. When I browse the URL using a browser, it returns html content. My code also sees the same html content instead of XML content.

Is there a way to get the XML content instead of html content? In the below code, I am getting only the html response. But if I check with postman plugin in chrome it shows a nice XML response. How do I get the same response using my code.

```
public static void sendURL(String urlValue)throws Exception{
    URL oracle = new URL("https://whois.arin.net/rest/asn/AS2639");

    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();

    yc.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/xml");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
yc.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/xml");
```

with this:

```
yc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
```

Indeed the main purpose is totally different, `Content-Type` describes what you have in the body of your request while `Accept` indicates to the server what kind of content the client can manage which is what you want to do.

**Content-Type:**

> The MIME type of the body of the request (used with POST and PUT
>   requests)

**Accept:**

> Content-Types that are acceptable for the response.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did the same and worked. Hope you understand my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>So you already have a stream. What you need to do next is to pass that stream to a library that can decode and parse XML. Try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse(org.xml.sax.InputSource)</strike>

**UPDATE**

Sorry, your initial question was not very clear. If your java invocation of the HTTP request is yielding HTML and the one you want is an XML response, there must be some difference between the HTTP requests you make through the browser and through Java. You can use a tool like TCPMON to sit between your backend and your Java program to capture the raw HTTP request and then compare that with the one you make through the browser.

Since HTTP is a request/response pair, equivalent HTTP requests should always send back the same response.

Comment: actually what my streams return is full of html and not xml. I don't see the xml response in anywhere of the html response

Comment: oh right, sorry your question wasn't very clear. If your browser invocation is sending XML and your request is sending back HTML, you should check the raw HTTP requests and compare them. You should be able to find what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Updated code. We just need to accept only the xml response.

```
public static void sendURL(String urlValue)throws Exception{
    URL oracle = new URL("https://whois.arin.net/rest/asn/AS2639");

    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();

    yc.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/xml");

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: Yes and my updated answer tells you why that is so. Missing the HTTP Accept header in your request was the issue and you can find that out using a tool like TCPMON.

Comment: I wouldn't do tcpmon stuff instead, I would search java docs to found my answer. Also, I still believe my question is extremely clear

Comment: I thought i posted it before you post or at least I didn't see you post till i post my answer. Unfortunately I don't know who posted first

Comment: No problem. take it. Still I believe my code explains everything. I don't want to write all the way.

Comment: @nicolas thanks. I will stick with my reply and let yours be the best!!